# How to set boot disk for SSD in google compute engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I try to create a click to deploy website site and select SSD as my pesistent disk
however after creation I can see that google created a normal 10GB disk as my boot and not the SSD one, how do I change that?

even though there is two pesistent disk now

Answer (score 0):

Which click-to-deploy machine have you created ? For example, using a LAMP stack, you sill the option to create a Data disk as SSD. This is not the same disk as your boot disk, it will be an additional one.

You may have to create the GCE instance from scratch using the Web GUI. In `Compute engine > Disks`, you have the option of creating SSD disks that can be used as boot when creating a new machine. After that is done, you can install your web server.

Comment: Hey I am using the wordpress click to deploy option.